# Нужно в цикле for сгенерировать 4 названия функций в PHP

Tags: php

Добрый вечер, друзья.
Нужна помощь. Мне нужно внутри цикла for в PHP выводить function, в названии которых будут сгенерированные числа-дополнения. То есть мне нужно сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++ ) {
    function block_content_$i (){
        // func body
    }
}
```

Этот код должен выдать в итоге такое:

```
function block_content_1() {
    // func body
}
function block_content_2() {
    // func body
}
function block_content_3() {
    // func body
}
function block_content_4() {
    // func body
}
```

Естественно, это не работает. Помогите, разобраться. Заранее, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, зачем вам куча одинаковых функций, но можно вот так:

```
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++ ) {
    ${"block_content_$i"} = function () use ($i) {
        echo $i;
    };
}
$block_content_1(); // 1
```

---

Без переменных я вижу лишь один путь, который не должен быть упомянут)

```
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++ ) {
  $func = "function block_content_$i(){}";
  eval($func);
}
```

Comment: Большущее спасибо! Первый вариант - то, что нужно. Но теперь вопрос - как вывести $block_content_1(); в другом файле PHP? :)

Comment: `require_once` этот файл

Comment: А вообще, завязывайте вы с этим делом. Вы совершенно точно что-то делаете не так.

Comment: Да, уже запутался тут :) Спасибо